# RegEx validation for numbers only with a minimum length

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

so i have this reg ex

```
0*[0-9]\d*
```

which accepts numbers only how would i, make it to accepts numbers only but have a minimum input of 5 numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I this will do what you're wanting.

```
^\d{5,}$
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean `exactly 5`? However OP asks for `at least 5`.

Comment: thank you sir this is what im looking for i just need to add a comma after the 5, one quick question what does $ mean?

Comment: @AsshO.Le: `^` begin of line, `$` end of line.

Comment: If you actually want to make it mean "exactly 5" then use Bobby's original answer which he edited to properly answer the above question: ^\d{5}$  ...Adding the comma makes it minimum of 5 or greater

Answer (score 9):

Here's a template for you:

```
<expression>{length}
<expression>{min,}
<expression>{min,max}
```

In your case it will be:

```
\d{5,}
```

See the [sandbox](http://rubular.com/r/nx4nYTyzXi).

Answer (score 3):

To specify the minimum ammount of symbols use `{n,}` where `n` is 5 in your example, so regex would be `\d{5,}`

```
String pattern = @"\d{5,}";
var result = Regex.Match("12345", pattern);
```